# Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from binary to BIT is unsupported

Tags: sql-server, spring, jpa

In SQL Server database + Spring, I am getting this error

Can someone help.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from binary to BIT is unsupported

In spring I have used

```
repo.findByFlagTrue(pageable)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your code.

Comment: You should change it to a `bit` column

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved

I have used `Binary(1)` for flag column after updating by `tinyint` it is working fine.

```
alter column [flag] tinyint
```